# mysql query to vb.net line chart

Tags: mysql, vb.net, linechart

I'm creating a trend (line chart) in vb.net populating with data from a mysql database.  Currently, I have x-axis as datetime and y-axis as just a test value (integer).  As in most HMI/SCADA trends you can pause, go back, fwd (scroll) in the trend (I just have buttons).  I have my y-axis interval changeable.  So, what I do is look at the Id from the DB as min/max.  Then when I want to scroll left/right I just increment/decrement the min/max and then use these new values for my where clause in the sql query.  All of this works very well.  It seems to have very little overhead and is very fast/responsive.  So far I have tested with over 10 million rows and don't see any noticeable performance difference.  However, at some point in time my Id (being auto increment) will run out.  I know it's a large number but depending on my poll rate it could fill up in just a few years.

So, does anyone have a better approach to this?  Basically I'm trying to eliminate the need to query more points than what I can view in the chart at one time.  Also, if I have millions of rows I don't want to load these points if I don't have to.  I also need to have this somewhat future proof.  Right now I just don't feel comfortable with it.

Comment: If you use a 64-bit number as your ID and generate one record every millisecond, you'll run out of IDs after 292,471,208 and 2/3 years.  I think you'll be fine.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the response.  So, using bigint along with "dropping" data after so long and I guess I will be fine.  I guess I made this a bigger deal than I needed.

Comment: What's the preferred method to delete/drop data after so many records or time?

Comment: I'm not sure that there is a best practice where that's concerned.  You could possibly have a console app executed by a scheduled task that connected to the database and deleted everything older than a particular date based on today's date, possibly after archiving it to another table or even another database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I have researched online and found several options.  I feel better about this solution.  Thanks again.